# JUnit Integration Testing NamedJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, database, junit, mockito, namedparameterjdbctemplate

I have a Repository class RaRepository as below

```
@Repository
public class RaRepository{
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<raAttribute> findFieldsByItemId(list<string> itemsId){
String sql = "select * from abc where id in (:itemsId)";
SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource("itemsId",itemsId);
List<raAtrribute> raAttList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, param, 
(rs, rowNum) -> new raAtrribute(rs.getString(ps_name)));

return raAttList;
}

}
```

I have written a Junit Test class as below

```
public class RaRepositoryTest {
@Autowired 
Private RaRepository raRepository;

@Test
public void findFieldsByItemId(){
List<String> itemsId = new ArrayList<>();
itemsId.add("VZ203")
List<raAttribute> raAttlist = raRepository.findFieldsByItemId(itemsId);
Assert.assertEquals(2, raAttlist.size);
}
```

The datasource written in application.properties file. I need to connect to actual db and run tests. I have tried with annotations like @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), @DataJdbcTest etc. I am new to jdbctemplate and not sure how to write test case for above scenario to achieve db connectivity.

Note: Iam using JUnit4 andService class which actually calls findFieldsByItemId method have separate mocking unit test.

Comment: Try to use @SpringBootTest above the "public class RaRepositoyTest {". Are you sure the Spring is reading application.properties correct? Try either: @ActiveProfiles("test") // using for example src/test/resources/application-test.properties

Comment: What effect do you observe when executing your test when using these annotations? `@DataJdbcTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` seem like good choice of annotations if using jUnit4. (you need both)

Comment: It worked with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class). however I had to create separate class which initialized data Source  with @Bean annotation for the SpringRunner before running test case.

Comment: @Lucas,Lesiak- Can you check for this once? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75446117/mock-namedparameterjdbctemplate-with-callback-function?noredirect=1#comment133118441_75446117